Both one and two hashes in macro parameter seem to work
This question refers to egreg's answer to my earlier question that eventually became the package keytheorems. Here is egreg's code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mbert/thmstyle }
  {
    spaceabove .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_spaceabove_tl,
    spacebelow .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_spacebelow_tl,
    bodyfont .tl_set:N  = \l_mbert_thmstyle_bodyfont_tl,
    headindent .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_headindent_tl,
    headfont .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_headfont_tl,
    headpunct .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_headpunct_tl,
    postheadspace .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thmstyle_postheadspace_tl,
    headstyle .code = \cs_set:Nn \mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn{#1},
  }

\tl_new:N \l_mbert_thmstyle_default_tl
\keys_precompile:nnN { mbert/thmstyle }
  {
    spaceabove = \topsep,
    spacebelow = \topsep,
    bodyfont = \itshape,
    headindent = 0pt,
    headfont = \bfseries,
    headpunct = {.},
    postheadspace = 5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
    headstyle = \mbert_thmstyle_name:n{#1}\mbert_thmstyle_number:n{~#2}\mbert_thmstyle_note:n{~#3},
  }
  \l_mbert_thmstyle_default_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mbert_thmstyle_name:n { \thmname{#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mbert_thmstyle_number:n { \thmnumber{#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mbert_thmstyle_note:n { \thmnote{#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewThmStyle}{mm}
  {
    \tl_use:N \l_mbert_thmstyle_default_tl
    \keys_set:nn { mbert/thmstyle } {#2}
    \mbert_thmstyle_new:nVVVVVVVe{#1}
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_spaceabove_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_spacebelow_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_bodyfont_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_headindent_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_headfont_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_headpunct_tl
      \l_mbert_thmstyle_postheadspace_tl
      {\mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn{##1}{##2}{##3}}
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \mbert_thmstyle_new:nnnnnnnnn \newtheoremstyle
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mbert_thmstyle_new:nnnnnnnnn { nVVVVVVVe }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThmStyle{teststyle}{headstyle={#2 -- #1}}
\NewThmStyle{teststyle2hashes}{headstyle={##2 -- ##1}}

\theoremstyle{teststyle}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\theoremstyle{teststyle2hashes}
\newtheorem{test2}{Test Two}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
text
\end{test}

\begin{test2}
text
\end{test2}

\end{document}


As you can see, the headstyle key that defines \mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn seems to be able to take macro parameters with either one or two hashes. How can this be? Even this works:
\NewThmStyle{teststyle1and2hashes}{headstyle={##2 -- #1}}

Ulrich Diez's comprehensive answer to my previous question explains

During expansion of a macro a single hash-character-token of category 6(parameter) (#6) occurring in the macro's ⟨definition⟩'s ⟨replacement text⟩ trailed by one of the digit-character-tokens of category 12(other) 112, 212, 312, 412, 512, 612, 712, 812, 912, is taken for a parameter which is to be substituted by a macro argument. But two consecutive hash-character-tokens of category 6(parameter) (#6#6) occurring in the ⟨replacement text⟩ just collapse into a single one which is not taken for a parameter-thingie, but, like other tokens of the ⟨replacement text⟩, is inserted into the token-stream as is. Thus hashes that shall go into the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the macro \thmstyleheadcmd in a way where they are not taken for parameter-thingies of the ⟨replacement text⟩ but are delivered as is, need to be doubled. The doubling of hashes within the ⟨replacement text⟩ of a ⟨definition⟩ can be achieved via combining \edef with \unexpanded as in \edef\macro{\unexpanded{At the time of expanding, the following yields a single hash character token of category 6(parameter): #}}.

Now this is not the easiest thing to understand, but I don't think this explanation leads one to conclude "either one or two hashes produce the same result" (but it very well might!).
So my question is somewhat soft: what exactly is happening here? Does it matter that amsthm is storing this definition in a toks register (see, for example, here)? A minimal example showing this behavior would be very much appreciated.

Short answer: it works by chance.

\mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn{##1}{##2}{##3} ...

@egreg like most of your answers

@egreg I am interested in the long answer :)

@DavidCarlisle Sure but that's inside the definition of another command so has to have two hashes. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment

the point is as it is just passing on three arguments in the same order then in its expansion (the argument  passed above) and ##1 (the argument passed here end up being the same,


As \mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn{##1}{##2}{##3}
is just passing on three arguments in the same order then in its expansion #1 (the argument passed above) and ##1 (the argument passed here) end up being the same
A simpler example producing the output above with a/b whether # or ## is used.

\def\ldef#1{%
  \def\ww##1##2##3{%
    \def\foo####1####2####3{#1}\foo{##1}{##2}{##3}}%
  \ww{a}{b}{c}
  \show\foo
}


  \ldef{#1/#2}

  \ldef{##1/##2}

\bye

The terminal log shows that the first time
> \foo=macro:
#1#2#3->a/b.

so the inner macro doesn't use its arguments its replacement text is fixed by the arguments of the calling macro.
The second time
> \foo=macro:
#1#2#3->#1/#2.

so now the inner macro does use its arguments but as these are necessarily the same as the arguments of the macro that defined it, the final output is the same.

Weird... I could not have come up with this by myself. Thanks

@mbert just spend 30 years looking at \tracingall output then you will spot these effects straight away:-)

how do you get from the code in the question to this?

@cfr as I commented under the question I knew from the title that \mbert_thmstyle_headcmd:nnn{##1}{##2}{##3} was the issue so simplified that to \foo{##1}{##2}{##3} then a couple of minutes playing around to surround that with the right number of \def to get the # or ## behaviour. I didn't actually trace the code path in the question.
